# Searching for numbers with a comma as a decimal point in an array

Tags: php, regex

I have to search through an Excel file and get the numbers that have a comma as a decimal point and convert it to a decimal point.(ex: 23,56 -> 23.56, 23123,566 -> 23123.566). I have already exported the excel file to .csv and put all contents into arrays but I have trouble finding the numbers with comma.
This is how one of my array looks like:

```
    Array
    (
        [A1] => 1
        [A2] => 123123
        [A3] => dasdadwa
        [A4] => 6,7
        [A5] => 24f,5
        [A6] => f5,5
        [A7] => dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd
        [A8] => aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        [A9] => dasdasd
        [A10] => q231e
        [A11] => 
        [A12] => 0
        [A13] => 
        [A14] => 
        [A15] => 1
        [A16] => 123123
        [A17] => dasdadwa
        [A18] => 6,7
        [A19] => 24f,5
        [A20] => f5,5
        [A21] => dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd
        [A22] => 
        [A23] => 
        [A24] => q231e
        [A25] => 
        [A26] => 0
        [A27] => 
        [A28] => 
        [A29] => 1
        [A30] => 123123
        [A31] => dasdadwa
        [A32] => 6,7
        [A33] => 24f,5
        [A34] => f5,5
        [A35] => dasdad,fsdfsdfsfsasada dasdasd
        [A36] => 
        [A37] => 
        [A38] => q231e
        [A39] => 
        [A40] => 
        [A41] => 
        [A42] => 
    )
```

I'm only interested in the characters that have only numbers and a comma but it is troublesome because those entries are strings. I have tried messing with regex but I just could not get it to work.
Here is what i have so far:

```
    function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
    {
        if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
            return FALSE;

        $header = NULL;
        $data = array();
        if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
        {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
            {
                if(!$header)
                    $header = $row;
                else
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        return $data;
    }

$contents = csv_to_array($filename.'.csv');

    foreach($contents as $val) 
    {

        //If $val is a number separated by comma
             //Replace comma with . (str_replace(',','.');, $val);)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple pattern which will replace only your pattern:

```
//rest od your code and now:
foreach($contents as $key => $val) 
{
  $contents[$key] = preg_replace('/^(\d+),(\d+)$/', '\1.\2', $val);
}
```

This code will touch only strings like `2,3`. Strings like this `ff,333` will not be touch

Comment: Worth adding a link to http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: It seems the issue dealing with German number formatting, which would also have dots as thousand separators. It could be worth updating your answer to support these. But I agree preg_replace would be the way to go.

Comment: @R.Chappell well, OP didn't mention about German numbers in his excel so I am not sure if I should make this reg pattern more complicated

Comment: @nospor true that, I might have reading too much into it. Maybe Sebastian would give us more detail.

Comment: @R.Chappell yes, let's wait for Sebastian's feedback :)

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! Oddly enough I work with german databases but i haven't seen dots as thousand separators before. For this example though this solution might be the way to go.

Comment: OK, so here is quick fix if there are german numbers: `$val = preg_replace('/^(\d+)\.?(\d+),(\d+)$/', '\1\2.\3', $val);` :)

Comment: And another fix: `$val = preg_replace('/^(\d+)(\.(\d+))?,(\d+)$/', '\1\3.\4', $val);` previous has one bug

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to extract only decimals, I suggest using regex, like this:

```
foreach($contents as $val) {
    // if $val is a number separated by comma
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/', $val) == 1) {
         // transform into float with two decimals and dot as decimal separator
         $float = number_format($val, 2, '.');
    }
}
```

Edit: updated regex pattern following comments.

Comment: Your code will be wrong for strings like this `fff2,3`

Comment: And if there is only one character you really do not have to use {1}

Comment: Yes, that's better :)

Answer (score -3):

Like this?

```
foreach($contents as $val) 
{
    if (strpos($val, ',') !== false) {
        $val = str_replace(',', '.', $val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will replace also ff,333 into ff.333 which is wrong